# Uncheck slider checkbox with vba + selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

below is the code to find a checked slider checkbox :

```
    For Each Aelement In browser.FindElementsById("compte-alertes").First.FindElementsByTag("div")
        If Aelement.Attribute("class") = "slider_checkbox checked" Then
           '?
        End If
    Next
```

I want to uncheck the slider checkbox.
(if I manually uncheck, Aelement.Attribute("class") = "slider_checkbox")

```html
<div id="compte-alertes" class="bloc box-shadow ">
  <div class="bandeau fond-noir">
  <div class="content">
     <table id="mes-helpers">
       <tr class="gameplay-preference ......
          <td>...</td>
         <td>
            <div class="slider_checkbox checked"><input type="checkbox" id="alertes_alerteAutre" name="alertes[alerteAutre]" value="1" checked="checked"></div>
         </td>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: ok I have added it

Answer (score 0):

one solution is :

```
    For Each Aelement In browser.FindElementsById("compte-alertes").First.FindElementsByTag("div")
   ' "slider_checkbox" = Aelement
    If Aelement.Attribute("class") = "slider_checkbox checked" Then
       browser.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='mes-helpers']/tr[1]/td[2]/div").Click
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```